# Twitter API V1 still working

Tags: ios, twitter

In a current iOS app I'm using a TWRequest with the the url (http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json) to get a list of user_ids. This is still working even though the V1 API is deprecated. Does twitter auto redirect requests to the v1.1 api if the only difference is the version number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the V1 api calls are deprecated, but not removed. This was simply to give developers some time to migrate to V1.1. It is recommended that you migrate to V1.1, because eventually V1 may be removed.